# Unit Testing Meta Data - Java Script

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tags, metadata, html-head

I have meta data fields in certain pages that fill with something like this in the `head` of the html page:

```
<meta property="og:provider_name" content="ThisGuy">
```

I have lots of meta data that is filled in, and I would like to have a JS unit test so I could see later on if this ever doesn't work.

Is there anyway to do this? I am using Mocha and sinon if they are relevant.

Comment: What exactly do you need to identify that might not be working?